# Should there be the ability to contest a question being tagged as duplicate or off topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

There are a few instances of people being a little over-enthuastic (actually to the point of being pedantic) about flagging a question in some way, when it's a clear, useful and appropriate question.  Take this example (not my question).  This isn't off-topic (OK there could be opinion as to which is the best availabe Android browser), however it's a very clear, useful question that got plenty of upvotes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186145/android-browser-emulator

The question is, should there be the ability (or even is there a plan) to allow a flag to be contested, since it can get in the way of a developer getting responses to legitimate questions, or for an answer to added to or improved on by additional or newer suggestions being added in some cases.

Comment: Flag can be dismissed/contested by high rep users, yes. Actual close vote can't. On this case it was closed in one shot by a moderator, it requires 5 high rep (>3K) users to reopen it.

Comment: OK, thanks Sha.  How much rep is needed?

Comment: At 10K rep we get access to the flags queue where we can either agree with each flag, adding actual vote to close or dismiss the flag. At 3K rep, one can cast actual close vote.

Comment: That's absolutely off-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: OK, looks like the general feeling is that StackOverflow shouldn't be used for getting advice on tools, however I'd find it somewhat useful for this purpose as it allows developers to point out specific features, benefits or issues

Comment: @Chris did you read the reasoning behind why they are off topic?

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow everyone finds them valuable when they find the one specific tool that helps them.  But when you have hundreds of similar question, with 25 answers that only say "Hey, Foo is the best" (with Foo being the same or different in each answer), you'll see why they aren't good.  Oh yeah and then when there are 12 links pointing to Foo 3 years after Foo was last updated (or was last available), you'll hate them even more.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow ultimately there are other sites to ask these types of questions, but the community long ago they don't want them here because they tend to be a lot less valuable over time.

Comment: It's __ON TOPIC__ because it isn't asking for recommendations or ratings in any way.  It's just asking if there is one.  Huge Difference.

Comment: @LanceRoberts So you think a yes or no answer would be sufficient, or do you think maybe the OP would actually like to know what some of those browser emulators are?  Phrasing it to ask if there is one is just splitting hairs. It's not a huge difference at all.

Comment: I certainly think it's fine for people to give the name of a specific tool, we just don't need to get into a polling situation.  I have needed to find a software tool to use in the past and was happy for the help.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Then it's a recommendation question and it's off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Any user with 15+ rep is [capable of flagging posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).  Of the flags available to users from 15 rep to 2999 rep on a closed post, the mod attention would likely be the one to chose.  Explain fully the issue and what you believe to be the case and your argument for the post to be reopened.

At 3000 rep, users are able to cast [close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).  Close votes can close a question, reopen votes can reopen one that has been closed.

Those are the two ways to address the question of closed questions.

---

Closing a question is irrespective of the popularity of a question.  There can be very popular questions ("What is your favorite programming joke") that are not at all appropriate for StackOverflow.

The format of Stack Overflow is focused on being a question and answer site and strives (however difficult that is) for quality.  It is by maintaining that quality that it is able to keep its high SEO ratings and in turn, its business plan, which in turn keeps the lights on for the site.

---

On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186145/android-browser-emulator please note the diamond on the name of the person closing the question.  This was closed by a moderator.

Questions that are polling for answers or just 'yes' / 'no' answers (see [help - what types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) don't do a good job of being a good question.  Such questions tend not to create good answers (the polling answers often suffer from link rot, or get outdated).  Without people providing and updating the answers (there are far too many of them to curate), trying to support polls on the site is a loosing battle that eats away at the quality of the site.